# Generator Runtime error when added babel-preset-env and babel-preset-stage-2

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I had to use babel-preset-env and babel-preset-stage-2 in order to use webpack for a code that includes spread operator. After that I succeed in building my bundle with webpack but this time I get generator runtime error during runtime.

So first I tried to do solution in this page, babel-polyfill but my team did not want me to use it, instead they asked me to use transform-runtime plugin,so I installed it and put it in babelrc file but still getting same generator-runtime error, any idea about that ? What should I do more ?

here is babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-2",
    "es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    [
      "transform-runtime",
      {
        "helpers": false,
        "polyfill": false,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

webpack config file

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'partner/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'partner_bundle.js'
  },
  target: 'web',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // Check for all js files
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['babel-preset-env', 'babel-preset-stage-2'].map(
            require.resolve
          )
        },
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!other-module)/
      }
    ]
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: { symlinks: false }
}
```

babel and webpack versions in the package.json

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",

"webpack": "^4.0.1",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.9"
```

Comment: What version of webpack and babel are you using? The syntax has changed a bit on some of the newer versions.

Comment: I wrote babel wen webpack versions in the original post.

Comment: I added 'babel-preset-es2015' along with 'babel-preset-env' because previously I wasnt getting this error when I used only 'babel-preset-es2015', but still getting same runtime error

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-constant-elements"]
    }
  }
}
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/

Comment: I did it but still getting same error. here is my babelrc file. {
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-constant-elements",
          "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-react-constant-elements"],
    "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-2"
  ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: It gives error for this function state at last.   updateState (state) {
    this.peer.set(`${this.basePath}/states/`, state)
  }  and I noticed that there is also a state in class definition , this.state, so when I named this one as state1 it fixed. Or, if assign it to another varibale, I const state1 = state again fixed.

Comment: I think you're trying to make your .babelrc file more complicated than it needs to be. I don't think you need the "presets", and I'm not sure about the transform. It's seems like you're trying to use older configuration for babel, with newer version. Try using the simple setup. A lot of things are handled automagically now, that you used to have to do manually.